# Is there a way to recover the connection to my GCP VM?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

1. I have a GCP VM on which is installed a Docker with Drupal.
2. e2-medium with SSD 10Go
3. After increasing the disk size to 20GB, I can no longer access the VM in SSH

The manipulations that I tried

- Return to the starting configuration
- IAP configuration with dedicated address ranges to arrive on the VM subnet
- Connection to the serial port of the machine

This last point works, but I don't know what to check or what to look for to restart the VM

In the console logs, i have this:

```
  [{
"insertId": "2","jsonPayload": {
"lateBootReportEvent": {
 "actualMeasurements": [
 {
  "hashAlgo": "SHA1",
  "pcrNum": "PCR_14",
  "value": "xxwkxkw,xw"
  }
  ],
  "policyMeasurements": [
  {
  "value": "hhhh+jjjjj=",
  "hashAlgo": "SHA1",
  "pcrNum": "PCR_9"
  }
  ],
  "policyEvaluationPassed": false
},
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/cloud_integrity.IntegrityEvent",
"bootCounter": "31"
},
"resource": {
"type": "gce_instance",
"labels": {
  "instance_id": "00000000",
  "zone": "europe-000000
  "project_id": "HHHHHHHHH"
}
},
"timestamp": "2022-04-28T21:35:52.092570946Z",
"severity": "ERROR",
"logName": "/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Fshielded_vm_integrity",
"receiveTimestamp": "2022-04-28T21:35:54.103571412Z"
}]
```

Does the shielded_vm_integrity type error speak to you please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VM is failing to boot because of a boot integrity check. You resized the disk which changed the boot configuration.

The solution is to disable the shielded VM options:

- [Go to VM instances](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances)
- Click on the VM instance name to open the VM instance details page
- Stop the VM, wait for the VM to stop
- Click Edit
- Turn off Secure Boot
- Turn off vTPM
- Turn off Integrity Monitoring

CLI command:

```
gcloud compute instances update VM_NAME \
    --no-shielded-secure-boot \
    --no-shielded-vtpm \
    --no-shielded-integrity-monitoring
```

Once your VM is running successfully, you can enable these features.

[Determining the cause of boot integrity validation failure](https://cloud.google.com/compute/shielded-vm/docs/integrity-monitoring#diagnosing-failure)

[What is Shielded VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/shielded-vm/docs/shielded-vm)

There is a free book download on TPM which contains details on the Platform Configuration Registers mentioned in your logs (PCR-9 and PCR-14):

[A Practical Guide to TPM 2.0](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-1-4302-6584-9.pdf)

Comment: Hi John, thank for your assistance. I think the initial problem has been solved but I'm not able to tog on the VM using ssh. I'm using Google CLI, Putty, etc... and having a complete review for the whole conf but no way. I will closed this issue because it solve and request another one for SSH issue.